Splunk SPL Examples for WebSphere SystemOut Logs
We use Splunk, and I do know that our SystemOut logs are forwarded to the Splunk indexer.  Does anyone have some example SPLs for searching indexes for WebSphere SystemOut Warnings "W" and SystemOut Errors "E"?  Thanks.

For your reference, here is a link to IBM's WebSphere log interpretation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rtrb_readmsglogs.htm

Maybe ask this question at Splunk Community. Stack Overflow would be the place to ask if you have a problem or question regarding code (including SPL)
